# JQM Slider Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an issue where I am trying to set a UI slider's maximum value to an Ajax-derived value. My slider looks like this:

```
<input type="range" id="mwpSlider" min="1" max="100" value="1">
```

When the user clicks an icon an Ajax call is made to determine the maximum value of the slider. I then set the slider as follows:

```
 $("#mpwSlider").slider('option','max', maxValue);
 $("#mpwSlider").slider('value',1);
```

I have also tried:

```
$("#mpwSlider").val("1").slider('refresh');
```

And then show the  containing the slider. Regardless of what I do (including hardcoding a value of 2000 in place of maxValue), the max value remains 100. I am using JQM 1.4.1, JQ 1.10.2 and JQ-UI 1.8.23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo on the input Id. Even fixing that it won't work.

Try using the .prop and .val functions from jquery:

```
$("#mwpSlider").prop('min',1);
$("#mwpSlider").prop('max',maxValue);
$("#mwpSlider").val(1000)
$("#mwpSlider").slider("refresh");
```

Working example here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1mwwguy/)

Comment: Thanks. I stared at that forever and still missed the typo. I changed as you suggested. Now I can't get it to respond to an event if you have any ideas. The code is: $("#mwpSlider").on("slidestop", function(event,ui) {alert(ui.value)} );